# SQL Server 2005 Replication Subscription Expiring Warning

Tags: sql-server, alerts

This week one of my replication subscriptions expired because I wasn't getting any alerts saying that there was a login error (I've fixed those alerts and the error).  What I'd like now is, in the case that this happens again, to be able to send an alert saying that a subscription is about to expire (ie, it will expire in 1 or 2 days).  I have an alert set up for when a subscription expires, but this is after the fact.  I've looked through sys.messages for any text that has "Expir" in it, but I haven't found an appropriate error code yet.  Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: is this transactional or merge replication? push or pull?

Comment: transactional.  push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... This is the way I would go about it... you will need DB Mail enabled and a profile created and change those sections according to your environement below... also change the @MaxOfflineInHours= variable to whatever amount of hours of inactivity you would like to alert on... Create the stored procedure usp_GetExpiringSubscribersList then place the email script below in a SQL job and schedule it. The email script is designed to return a result set to you via email. Let me know if you have any issues with it and I can work through it with you. Let me know if you need anything else.
Thanks!
-VM

--==============================================================================

```
Create Procedure dbo.usp_GetExpiringSubscribersList

AS



declare @maxOffLineInHours int

set @maxOffLineInHours = 72 -- <SET YOUR NUMBER OF HOURS TO ALERT ON HERE>

SELECT srvname,

Max_start_time,

DATEDIFF(hh, Max_start_time, getdate())

FROM distribution.dbo.msmerge_sessions

JOIN ( SELECT agent_id,

Max_start_time = MAX(start_time)

FROM distribution.dbo.msmerge_sessions

GROUP BY agent_id

) AS k ON k.agent_id = 
distribution.dbo.msmerge_sessions.agent_id

AND distribution.dbo.msmerge_sessions.start_time = max_Start_Time

JOIN ( SELECT id AS agent_id,

srvname

FROM distribution.dbo.msmerge_agents

JOIN sys.sysservers ON sys.sysservers.srvid = distribution.dbo.msmerge_agents.Subscriber_ID

) AS l ON l.agent_id = k.agent_id

WHERE DATEDIFF(hh, max_start_time, GETDATE()) > @maxOffLineInHours 

ORDER BY DATEDIFF(hh, max_start_time, GETDATE()) DESC 





--====================================================================

-- Put this code in a SQL Job to run daily or whatever interval suits you



EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

@profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2008R2 Administrator',

@recipients = 'VinnyAdmin@Adventure-Works.com',

@query = 'exec dbo.usp_GetExpiringSubscribersList' ,

@subject = 'usp_GetExpiringSubscribersList',

@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Comment: I will try out this solution and let you know how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: those tables look like the ones used for merge replication :(

Answer (score 1):

The event id I believe you are looking for is 14160.  You can set up a SQL Server Agent alert to fire when this event occurs, and you can configure the Agent to email or page you.

Here's the info about the event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337416.aspx

Here's some instructions in setting up an alert: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175076.aspx

Comment: The threshold [%s:%s] for the publication [%s] has been set. One or more subscriptions to this publication have expired. 

This event will fire when the subscription has already expired...i'm looking for more of a warning so that i can manually run the subscription before it is expired.

Comment: You can set a threshold to allow the event to fire ahead of time. "When you enable a warning by using Replication Monitor or sp_replmonitorchangepublicationthreshold, you specify a threshold that determines when a warning is triggered. When that threshold is met or exceeded, a warning is displayed in Replication Monitor, and an event is written to the Windows event log. Reaching a threshold can also trigger a SQL Server Agent alert"  There's a link to show you how to do that.